# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to insert the data into my database which has 2 tables

Products
(ProductID): 1
(IDNumber) : 200900110
(ProductName) :  Pepsi

Order
(OrderID): 1 (Auto Increment by 1)
(ProductID):1
(Date): 1/1/2009

The code is this:

```
var db = new ProductOrder();
var idNum = from p in db.Product
            where p.IDNumber == 200900110 
            select p.ProductID; 

var order = new Order();
            order.productID = Convert.ToInt32(idNum);
            order.Date = DateTime.Now;
db.Order.InsertOnSubmit(nTime);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

After I run it gives me the error like this:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[System.Int32]'
>   to type 'System.IConvertible'

Comment: I hope no-one minds - I've fixed the indentation to show where the statements are more clearly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your query:

```
from p in db.Product
where p.IDNumber == 200900110
select p.ProductID
```

does not return a single result but a list of results. In your case this will be a list containing a single product id. You should modify it to this:

```
(from p in db.Product
 where p.IDNumber == 200900110
 select p.ProductID).Single()
```

If you run your code in the debugger and you hover your mouse over the `idNum` variable, you'll see that it is a `DataQuery` instance.